# change the asp.net user password while retrieving current password

Tags: asp.net

I'm using the `ChangePassword` method of membership provider to change the password and one of the requirement before calling the `ChangePassword` is to retrieve the current password. But I'm getting error:
padding is invalid and cannot be removed

below is my web.config:

```
<system.web>
    < machineKey validationKey="4FD671E39167DFB91A918018007D095E50B7D2971B01AEDE26A7233FD9CC4A470F80689997EC2C7BB515F9D82C8B4D1F3A8495193630B11E8401C96BD0A5A133"
                decryptionKey="ED1555E75C7B91738172E0086456C70B9CAA4C44214FC2B1907123993EA4FA53"
                validation="SHA1"
                decryption="AES"/>
....
< /system.web>
```

Comment: So are you getting the error when calling ChangePassword or when retrieving?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cheat, you reset the password to a known value first.

```
MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser();
string generated = user.ResetPassword();
user.ChangePassword(generated, *newPassword*);
```